# Significant difference between functional and procedural collection handling

Tags: java, design, coding-style, functional-programming, productivity

I'm planning an empirical study on function passing - specifically lambdas aka anonymous functions aka arrow functions. Now, although functional or even object-oriented approaches are highly favored over procedural/imperative programming nowadays, there seems to be very little empirical evidence for their superiority. Even though many different claims exist on why you're better off with *higher-order programming*¹, it's hard for me to construct cases that pose a chance for statistically significant differences.

> The code is more expressive, telling *what* to do and not *how*

Claims like these are nice from a subjective and aesthetic point, but they'd have to map to empirical differences in productivity or maintainability in order to have leverage.

Currently I'm focused on Java's Stream API since it brought a major shift in how you write Java. For the industry this was accompanied by big rewrites, demand for employee training and updates to IDEs without much evidence that it's far better than what we had before.

Here's an example of what I mean where in my opinion the lambda-based implementation likely won't yield better results - even taking into account that participants would have to know the Stream API on top of the language API.

```java
// loop-based
public int inactiveSalaryTotal(List<Employee> employees) {
    int total = 0;
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        if (!employee.isActive()) {
            total += employee.getSalary();
        }
    }
    return total;
}

// lambda-based
public int inactiveSalaryTotal(List<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
                   .filter(e -> !e.isActive())
                   .mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
                   .sum();
}
```

I personally rather suspect advantages regarding collection of streams but I'm doubting that the average Java developer knows the API surface well enough to not get stranded for certain tasks.

```java
// loop-based
public Map<String, Double> averageSalaryByPosition(List<Employee> employees) {
    Map<String, List<Employee>> groups = new HashMap<>();
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        String position = employee.getPosition();
        if (groups.containsKey(position)) {
            groups.get(position).add(employee);
        } else {
            List<Employee> group = new ArrayList<>();
            group.add(employee);
            groups.put(position, group);
        }
    }
    Map<String, Double> averages = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Employee>> group : groups.entrySet()) {
        double sum = 0;
        List<Employee> groupEmployees = group.getValue();
        for (Employee employee : groupEmployees) {
            sum += employee.getSalary();
        }
        averages.put(group.getKey(), sum / groupEmployees.size());
    }
    return averages;
}

// lambda-based
public Map<String, Double> averageSalaryByPosition(List<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream().collect(
            groupingBy(Employee::getPosition, averagingInt(Employee::getSalary))
    );
}
```

#### Specific Question

Can you construct an exemplary case where lambda-based collection handling outperforms procedural handling (looping) by much in regard to either comprehension time, writing time, ease of change or time it takes to perform a specific task like fixing a bug as well as counting certain calls or parameters. I'm also very much interested in how you think it performs better, because least LOC isn't really what I'm looking for here but rather something that can be measured in time - eventually with the average Java developer. Outperforming is also explicitly not meant in regard to runtime performance.

Examples can be pseudo-code or any language supporting both paradigms such as Java, JavaScript, Scala, C#, Kotlin.

---

*¹ with the main focus on function passing, I'm assuming OOP and FP to be somewhat isomorphic for this purpose (type systems aside) since you could view an object as just a tuple of functions. With objects being able to accept and return other objects you've basically got higher-order functions*

Comment: This is a very good question. The same essential question seems to crop up in many guises - imperative/declarative, procedural/functional, "RBAR"/set-based, and so on.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Your second example clearly shows how to implement a functionality in 5 lines of code instead of 23 with way less boilerplate code, in a simpler to understand manner. Do you want more of such examples? That's not what this site will provide, questions for [list-of-things](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed) will always get closed as "too-broad".

Comment: As for ¹: Isn't the same true for imperative programming where you can just pass in a function pointer? Since functions can then also accept and return other functions, they too could be considered isomorphic.

Comment: Are there many examples of scientifically reliable quantitative proof that some way to write code is bettter than another? I think asking for one is not constructive way. I think your own example 2 is as good as it gets.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not asking for a list but rather for examples showing superiority of lambda-based collection handling. Further I wasn't implying that lambdas are always superior, yet for things like collection handling they seem to be commonly viewed as such. I'm okay if it's just in regard to collection as in my second example, yet that case has something different to it than other Stream API operations - it requires more knowledge about collecting APIs and available types. It's also not self-evident that the lambda approach is simpler to understand in all it's depth there.

Comment: @DelusionalLogic technically you could, but once you pass functions around, you're doing some kind of FP which is supposed to be contrasted here with imperative aproaches

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be about functional programming to me.   The stream libraries sit at a higher level of abstraction compared with plain 'foreach' loops.   It's often going be the case that using an abstraction *for its intended purpose* is going to result in more concise and expressive code than writing it out long-form using simple programming constructs such as if/else/for/while.   It's similar to comparing RegEx for extracting a simple pattern with foreach/string.split/etc.

Comment: Most of the functional "magic" is in high level function `groupingBy()`.  If one wrote a procedural equivalent, the procedural code would be much simpler.

Comment: Aside: Whenever i see `public Bar frob(List<Foo> foos) { return foos.stream(). ... }` I want to change it to `public Bar frob(Stream<Foo> foos)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> least LOC isn't really what I'm looking for here

But, why? Least LOC is what you **should** be looking for here. While lines-of-code does not make for a truly reliable maintainability measure, you will be hard pressed to disagree that it takes you more time to read 20 lines over 5 lines. Programming is not only about writing. It is also about **reading**.

Let me give you a very draft empirical way of judging the usefulness of "arrows".

Here is your code, copied **almost** verbatim, but with a minor change that probably makes all the difference in the world. This is what you will use to find out how useful "arrow-style" methods are in the end. This is your experimental material!

```java
// loop-based
public Map<String, Double> whatDoesThisFunctionDo(List<Employee> employees) {
    Map<String, List<Employee>> groups = new HashMap<>();
    for (Employee employee : employees) {
        String position = employee.getPosition();
        if (groups.containsKey(position)) {
            groups.get(position).add(employee);
        } else {
            List<Employee> group = new ArrayList<>();
            group.add(employee);
            groups.put(position, group);
        }
    }
    Map<String, Double> averages = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Employee>> group : groups.entrySet()) {
        double sum = 0;
        List<Employee> groupEmployees = group.getValue();
        for (Employee employee : groupEmployees) {
            sum += employee.getSalary();
        }
        averages.put(group.getKey(), sum / groupEmployees.size());
    }
    return averages;
}

// lambda-based
public Map<String, Double> whatDoesThisFunctionDo(List<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream().collect(
            groupingBy(Employee::getPosition, averagingInt(Employee::getSalary))
    );
}
```

Show the first function to some people and measure the average time it takes them to understand the **intended meaning**. Then show the second function to some **other** (obviously) people, again measuring the average time to total comprehension. Ask them to simply produce a suitable name for the function. Compare the results. Calculate the comprehension improvement ratio. Maybe you can get some statistically significant differences there!

> The code is more expressive, telling what to do and not how

Yes, it definitely is!

> Claims like these are nice from a subjective and aesthetic point, but they'd have to map to empirical differences in productivity or maintainability in order to have leverage.

Well, apply the ratio obtained above (which is just empirical, based on the specific functions you showed to the coders) in the case of having a class with 5 methods, or 10 methods. Differences will tend to become significant pretty quickly!

---

From the outside world, I read the name of the functions you posted and I "get the point". But this should not distract you or anyone from the fact that **someone, somewhere, will have to "get the point" not from the name, but from the content**. Someone will also have to **produce** the content. Someone will have to **review** the content. There is nothing aesthetic or subjective about less effort **typing**, less effort **thinking**, less effort **reviewing**, less room for **bugs**, less **training effort for newcomers**, etc. These things directly translate to productivity and, as a result, correlate inversely with spent resources!

I understand this may not be the answer you are looking for, but, IMHO, there is objective, nontrivial and **measurable** value in **keeping it short, simple and expressive**.

Comment: (similar comment is above under the question)  I like the functional code, but most of the functional "magic" is in high level function `groupingBy()`.  If one wrote a procedural equivalent, the procedural code would be much simpler, and intended meaning would be more or less as clear as the functional.

Comment: @user949300 true, but once you start introducing higher order functions like `groupingBy`, your "imperative" code starts becoming functional (or at least, functional-like) code :)

Comment: @AndresF.Yes, and isn't that a good thing to transition programmers?

Answer (score 3):

You have already accepted and answer and this is a bit of a side-note but I have never been really happy with the streams API in Java.  The design is very OO-centric and (ironically) somewhat procedural which can lead to very ugly (and unreadable) code IMO.  It's unfortunate since the features around function references that were introduced at the same time can avoid a lot of that noise.   For that same reason, it's pretty easy to create reusable functions that clean things up.  Here's how the first example looks once you introduce this:

```
public int inactiveSalaryTotal(List<Employee> employees) {
  return sum(map(filter(employees, Employee::isActive), Employee::getSalary);
}
```

This gives you something that is a bit more like how things are done in a true functional language.  It's more concise and, I think, understandable.  There are various ways these can be defined depending on your needs.  I can provide some example implementations if needed.

Comment: The major difference here is the operations read out -> in, rather than left -> right. Java does at least match English in that regard

Comment: Well, in those langs people also tend to use some kind of piping/chaning to avoid such nesting and thus end up with the same order you'll get with the Stream API. Being able to call the operations on a `Stream` object might also make the API more approachable/explorable

Comment: @Caleth I'm not so sure.  'The sum of the salaries of active employees' is a perfectly valid English sentence.  'Find the active employees and sum their salaries' is also valid.  The main difference is that the first is more declarative and the second is more imperative.

Comment: @nilo Pipelines are an option but I'm not convinced they are a preference.  LISPs are famous for their nested code structure.  As far as exploring, I don't disagree but such a design is limited (in Java) to what is defined.  It's not a problem per se as long as you realize you can always use functions to extend those capabilities as in this answer.  The main thing I dislike about streams, though, is that they require a lot of boilerplate like `stream()` and `collect()` and that you can't using them directly in an enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 2):

As a general note, it would be incorrect to say that the "functional" code (or the code using Java streams) is **always** better than the "imperative"  code (or the code using Java loops). In some cases it is much better, but in some cases it can make the code less readable. For a detailed analysis, see Item 45 (Use streams judiciously) in the third edition of the "Effective Java" book.

That being said, it is easy to find cases where your first stream example could be easily improved, while your first loop example couldn't. Imagine that you also need a function that calculates the total salary of the blue-haired employees, and  similar functions for green-haired, orange-haired, etc. employees. In the imperative version you would end up with a copy-paste nightmare, but in the functional version you could just pass the filtering predicate as an additional function argument.

```
public int salaryTotal(List<Employee> employees, Predicate<Employee> condition) {
    return employees.stream()
                    .filter(condition)
                    .mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
                    .sum();
}
```

Of course you could pass the Predicate to the procedural/imperative method (as a popular comment pointed out), but then it would become functional (a higher-order function). The *essence* of functional programming is to find declarative, readable ways to combine small, obviously correct functions into one complex functionality, and the Stream API is just one way to achieve this.

Another example would be the handling of future events. Imagine that you want to process all employees who will employed in the future: a nice unknown and potentially infinite list of events. They can't be iterated in a loop, but they still can be processed in a declarative way using a reactive stream library. The same would be very unreadable using imperative code.

Comment: Note: Nothing stops you from using Predicate also outside of stream API. You can just call its "test" method.

Comment: @Josef I didn't say that Predicate can be only used inside the stream API. You could pass it to the imperative version, but then it would become functional (a higher order function), and the essence of the question was about procedural vs functional and not about loops vs streams. Anyway, I will add some clarifications...

Comment: Thanks for your input! Maybe Josef had the same thought I had: you could have a method called `test` next to `salaryTotal` which you'd call from inside `salaryTotal` either way, then you can change the condition just as easy without using higher order functions.

Comment: @nilo But how would the test method know which test to perform? The blue-haired test or the orange-haired test? You could introduce global variables, but this is just as error-prone and hard to read as the copy-paste method...

Comment: @Ibalazscs You're right, you couldn't reuse the code inside `salaryTotal` when you'd want to perform it with different tests - I just referred to ease of change of the condition when coding. This is probably a very good point in regard to behavior parameterization, thanks!