# What is the benefit of Java collection streams over C# or Scala collections?

Tags: java, c#, scala, standard-library

Java collection streams were introduced in Java 8, which came out in March of 2014.

By that time, we already had well-established mechanisms for manipulating collections in several other languages, at least two that I can speak of:

- In C#, Linq provides extension methods such as `Select()`, `Where()`, etc. including collector methods such as `ToList()`. Parallel extensions have been supported with PLinq since 2010.
- In Scala, built-in collections have functions such as `map()`, `flatMap()`, `filter()`, etc. including collector methods such as `collect()`.  Parallel collections have been supported since 2011.

Since the creators of java decided that java collection streams are worthy of including in Java 8, they must think that java collection streams offer something which the (arguably simpler) pre-existing mechanisms do not.

So, what do java collection streams offer which Scala and C# collections do not?

Comment: I posted this question on stackoverflow yesterday, but it was closed as "primarily opinion based".  This is preposterous, because there exist possible definitive answers, such as "java collection streams can do X which C# and Scala cannot do", but in any case, even if we are to assume this is opinion-based, I suppose "SE" is more opinion-friendly.

Comment: _"What is the benefit of java collection streams?"_ is a very different question from "What can Java's Streams do that this other thing cannot", which is different from what the body text would suggest, which is "Why bother when we can do it already with this other thing". Judging by your rep here and elsewhere, I assume I'm missing the point of the question: could you maybe clarify it and the title?

Comment: @VisualMelon you are right, it is a very different question.  I have been unable to come up with a better title.  I will think about it.

Comment: @VisualMelon I edited both title and question, but I am still not sure I am getting my message across.

Comment: Ah, so are you asking why the Java Stream were designed in a way that is not (near enough) identical to existing solutions in different languages? (i.e. what motivates having a _different_ design, as opposed to what would motivate including it at all).

Comment: @VisualMelon yes.

Comment: The SE.SE community is definitely not "opinion-friendly", questions like this one are usually downvoted, close-voted and deleted here, sorry.

Comment: But FWIW, your literal question looks trivial: Java collection streams work in Java programs, Scala and C# collections do not. But that is not what you mean, I guess? Or do you mean why Java collection streams are not designed the way like, for example, Linq was designed in C#? Then you should ask exactly this (and explain what the differences between the designs are, since it seems you know them).

Comment: @DocBrown I guess I need to distance myself from the question to figure out why it is so hard to perfectly understand and see what I can do to improve it.

Answer (score 8):

> we already had well-established mechanisms for manipulating collections in several other languages [...]. Since the creators of java decided that java collection streams are worthy of including in Java 8, they must think that java collection streams offer something which the (arguably simpler) pre-existing mechanisms do not."

I think you're starting from a wrong assumption here - namely, that these are fundamentally different mechanisms.

They are not. They are all different forms of the same thing, just made to fit within their respective languages. It's all based on the same underlying principle - there's a set of useful methods that work on collections and provide some generalized algorithm, with an aspect that the caller can customize by providing a specific strategy for it.

Take, for example, the projection operation - known as `Select` in C#, or as `map` in Scala and other languages such as JavaScript. It goes through the collection and "projects" each element into something else; you usually pass in a lambda as the projection strategy, that the underlying algorithm then uses. Or take filtering - C#'s `Where` and Scala's `filter` let you pass in a filtering strategy - a lambda that decides which elements to keep. (I'm using the Strategy Pattern terminology here, as this is an example of it, except that it's on the level of functions.)

Now, the exact way each language goes about implementing support for this same concept has to do, at least in some significant part, with its history, and the need to minimize breaking changes. C# had delegates (somewhat fancy function pointers) early on. That made passing functions around as parameters easy. It also had the notion of an `IEnumerable<T>` - a thing that can be enumerated (Iterator pattern); this was used internally by the `foreach` loop. When they introduced LINQ, they recognized that they could leverage these, and that a `IEnumerable<T>` can be seen as the most suitable/versatile generalization of a collection (as opposed to some other interfaces that were also implemented by collections). LINQ methods are just static methods that take in an `IEnumerable<T>` and a delegate. To make things smoother, they came up with extension methods (which is just some syntactic sugar that lets you write certain static methods using the member access notation - so that it reads as `someCollection.Select(selectorFunc)` instead of `Select(someCollection, selectorFunc)`, and they added support for lambda expressions - inline ad hoc functions which could be bound to delegate-typed parameters. LINQ methods return lazily evaluated `IEnumerable<T>`-s; the processing isn't actually done until the result is enumerated. `ToList` differs somewhat from Scala's `collect`, but `ToList` does force the enumeration to happen, and then returns a list. So, the language designers found a nice way to introduce functional-style collection processing to the language without causing too much fuss.

Java on the other hand, didn't have delegates. It also had some of its own idiosyncrasies to deal with - like the distinction between primitive and non-primitive types, and the fact that primitive types can't be used for generic type arguments. In comparison, C# has a less heterogeneous type system, and a more unified system of abstractions; e.g., in C#, an array is an `IEnumerable`, while in Java an array is *not* an `Iterable`, and as a result the compiler has to treat it as a special case to make it work in a foreach loop.

Java people came up with what they called *functional interfaces*. A C# delegate defines a function signature; another way to think about it is that such a type is a lot like a single-method interface. A functional interface us just that - a type represented by a single-method interface (single abstract method). Java 8 lets you bind a lambda to a variable of such a type; in particular, you can have it be a parameter to a function.

As for Streams, my guess is that they needed to come up with a unified abstraction for all collections. C# was able to leverage `IEnumerable`, but I'm guessing Java people couldn't as easily use `Iterable` for various reasons (technical, political). 
But, hey, *composition is a flexible alternative to inheritance*, so the common abstraction can be achieved using an *Adapter* - a wrapper that "translates" the interface of the wrapped object into something that client code can work with; in this case, client code is code that wants to use functional-style collection processing. They also had some other goals, like supporting generator functions and parallel processing.

So they designed a small hierarchy around the idea of a `BaseStream` (with a few subtypes to deal with the type system - `Stream`, `IntStream`, `DoubleStream`), and a bunch of helper methods and some supporting infrastructure, like `Spliterator`.

So, again, it's the same general concept in all these languages, it's just that Java language engeneers had their own set of challenges to solve. As for the specifics of why certain choices were made and not others, only they can answer that.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer.  That last paragraph, that's what I am trying to find out.  Of course I know these mechanisms accomplish the same thing.  But the java way is appreciably more convoluted and performs worse. Which is very bad for something that accomplishes the same thing as its predecessors. So they have had to have very good reason for doing it this way and not the way of the other languages.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I guess the key point here is what Filip wrote in *"the exact way each language goes about implementing support for this same concept has to do, at least in some significant part, with its history, and* **the need to minimize breaking changes**". So I would not overthink this.

Comment: @MikeNakis - I guess it is somewhat more convoluted, but I'm not sure why you think it performs worse compared to, say, C#'s LINQ (I'm not sure about Scala).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović not that it matters much, but since you ask: because a) I have debugged into java streams, thus taking a look "under the hood" so to speak, and I have been flabbergasted by the complexity, and by the not-terribly-well-performing constructs I have seen there.  b) I have written collections for java that work like Linq and I have benchmarked them against java streams. The result was damning for java streams.

Comment: @MikeNakis - if you look at LINQ [under the hood](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs), you'll find it to be surprisingly complex as well (although I admit I didn't examine it in great detail; also, the code is for reference and isn't necessarily representative of current production implementation).

Comment: @MikeNakis - Regarding (b), I don't doubt that, but one thing to consider is that Java streams likely had to support constraints and scenarios that the (I'm guessing more straightforward) LINQ-like code you've written didn't (I know that, e.g., game developers sometimes opt to avoid some data structures and algorithms from the C++ standard library (otherwise widely used) in favor of some custom-made implementation that's less general, more straightforward and more performant, i.e., one that's both good enough and better suited for what they need).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović the reference source is from .NET Framework: you can see the .NET Core (current) implementations on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs). Just as a point of information, C# long had annonyous 'inline' methods: it was only the `a => b` syntax that was added along with LINQ because presumably people didn't like the older `delegate (T a) { return b; }` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is like asking what Gmail offers that Outlook.com does not.

## It's not technical

No, **really**, I **do believe** that there is no *technical* reason behind this. What I am suspecting is that you are confusing the meaning of *simplicity*, although I am not certain about this.

> Since the creators of java decided that java collection streams are
> worthy of including in Java 8, they must think that java collection
> streams offer something which the (arguably simpler) pre-existing
> mechanisms do not.

I was not sure about it, until you mentioned (in a comment) that:

> I have debugged into java streams, thus taking a look "under the hood"
> so to speak, and I have been flabbergasted by the complexity, and by
> the not-terribly-well-performing constructs I have seen there.

It is not simple *internally* but it is very simple **externally**. But, what is simple? **Something that reminds you of things familiar**. It's all around, it's the pattern *du jour*. It's the iterator pattern, buffed up! You can now collect, map, flatten, select many, order, compare, distinct or zip your pants all over, **in Java**. You don't have to feel bad that your friends coding in *c#.net* have more expressive power.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21782569/10102452), which leads to [this source](https://web.archive.org/web/20170519181014/http://leftoblique.net/wp/2013/07/25/java-8-a-k-a-oracle-finally-catches-up-to-net-framework-3-0/), that I henceforth quote from:

> Java 8, or Oracle finally catches up to .NET Framework 3.0
>
> With Java 8, you can now use nearly all of the syntactic sugar you love from C# in Java.

**It's all about the "*market*"**. It's about direct or indirect profit. Having more followers, as well as **keeping and respecting** your existing followers is usually a very rewarding strategy. There was a time when I could not really get my head around the `Aggregate` method, but I had a feeling it is **very interesting**. When I finally grasped the concept and became more fluent and **actually managed to use it in *useful* code**, I got this exhilarating emotional state, I felt **happy** to be able to do such a complicated thing in **1 line of code**. I could **positively not** describe my feeling with words, but I knew that my programming language makers **are caring for me**.

Now I can take up Java and **feel at home**. The creators of Java probably **know** this, and they also know that they were somewhat late to this specific "functional-programming-ish" convenience that Java 8 streams offer. The absurd complexity and the lower performance is what you get when on too tight deadlines. Still, **it works** and **most use cases do not really suffer from these performance problems**. Most users will not care if they wait half a second to open a file, and most developers know that [fewer lines of more-readable code is wonderful for maintenance (and for mental health)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/401928/340885). If I were in their shoes, I would probably do this as well, I would rush to begin mitigating the "*competition*", and leave the optimizations for later.

So, all in all, I assume (at least part of) the reason was to keep up with the competition. In short, what Java **streams** offer, that C#.NET and Scala collections do not, is a way to **carry-over** knowledge and proficiency on this specific pattern, in **Java**. It's really just a way to make you **more productive**, in **Java**.